# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, gradle

Afer downloading the new Android SDK I'm getting following error:

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1"
```

**build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    'compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

I even deleted the entry `<version>21.0.0</version>` in 
`android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml`

I've found following [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72430#makechanges) on issue tracker.
It did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I found the solution.

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
}
```

I think that instead of 20.0.0, you can specify a different version if you use less than 20 targetSdkVersion.